# Static properties / methods memory allocation

Tags: c#-4.0, static, singleton

lets take this example, which I think covers all my questions:

```
class SomeClass
{
    static SomeType PropertyA
    {
        get
        {
            if (....)
                return MethodA();
            else
                return MethodB();
        }
    }

    static SomeType MethodA() { ... }
    static SomeType MethodB() { ... }
}
```

will calling a SomeClass.PropertyA property create a memory leak? My opinion is no, since the property itself doesn't have a backing field, which would create a memory leak. I ask this because I have read that static properties can create memory leak, but I think it is the backing field that is responsible for memory leak, since it holds a reference to instance.

So in above example, MethodA, MethodB, and PropertyA in above example should not create any memory leaks. Am I wrong about this?

Another question I have is: I have lots of classes that mostly do not have a state nor data. They are just acting as a proxy. Some of those methods are called very frequently. My question would be: should I make those classes singleton, static, or regular classes?

Perfect example would be a class that contains 5-10 methods, and executes some SQL queries.

1) If I have them as regular, then I would need to create them very often (on some user reaction), call some method, and then allow the to be garbage collected.

2) choosing between singleton and static, what would be the pros / cons?

3) If I had a class that contains proxy methods, but has 2-3 IDbCommands that contains 10 parameters each, and is beneficial to reuse them, would that change anything in choosing the correct pattern?

Edit: since I got some answers that confused me more, probably due to misunderstanding, I am going to post an answer to my 1st question. I have done a test, where I allocated a large byte array (300MB), which is retrieved through PropertyA (and MethodA). **Both PropertyA abd MethodA in above example will not hold a reference to this object**, after fetching it, so as soon as calling code is done with array, it will be handled by GC. So in case where we use static property with getter only, or static methods, there should not be any memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in above example, MethodA, MethodB, and PropertyA in above example should not create any memory leaks. Am I wrong about this?

If you mean they won't create or hold onto any memory, then that's true - the property itself will not hold memory.

Static fields do not create a "memory leak" - the type initializer for the type will be run prior to the first use of the class, and, if a field requires memory, the memory for that field will be allocated.  This memory is not cleared - if that's what you mean by a "leak" -but there is no instance to free, so this is expected and desired behavior.

Comment: I have updated the question to explain what I mean by memory leak. When you say "if a field requires memory, the memory for that field will be allocated", does that mean that SomeProperty would not contain a reference to SomeClass (in my first example)?

Comment: @Goran Yes, if "MethodA" or "MethodB" do not return null, of course.  But yeah, the field will hold a reference to the instance, and that will keep the reference from being garbage collected.

Comment: So, this is a memory leak, which means that above code that I have put is wrong code, and should never be used. Call to PropertyA returns different instance each time. This means that when calling code finishes use of SomeClass instance, this instance will never be collected (PropertyA has reference to it), but at the same time this object is not accessible any more, since a call to PropertyA getter would return a reference to new instance of SomeClass.

Comment: And does the same apply to static methods also, will in my example be 3 references to instance of SomeType: calling code, PropertyA and MethodA?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is a question: "what do the methods do and do they hold state and do they have or have not cleanup required beyond simple garbage collection?"

If they don't to all of the above, it stands to reason you won't have a leak. A leak only occurs if you don't do something about it and if nothing you do requires any action you don't have a leak.

These days it is more about "memory pressure" than leaks.

In general, I would favor the instance approach since that provides garbage collection and allows for mocking and testing scenarios more readily.

Static methods and variables are subject to the same issues as instance variables and methods so a leak, if possible, applies to both.

Comment: The question itself holds an answer to your question: they are just proxy methods, they do not have state, nor data. This (2nd) question is not related to memory leak, but only to what pattern to use. So, your advice is to have everything as regular class, and recreate them each time they are required? Singleton class is also ready for testing mocking (its a (single) instance class), so why not having it as singleton then?

Comment: I guess the point to my answer is this: if your whole chain of properties and methods hold no state (which you say they don't), then yes, you have no memory leak. If anywhere in that chain state is held, and that is state that is not overridden but added to as calls come in at runtime (e.g. some side-effect in your code keeps appending things to a static list, then you have a leak even though all of the above is static).